# PHP - How can I iterate through this json response?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I have a json response from an API and I can't create an array from it with "json_decode" in PHP to iterate through this as an array. I always get "NULL", when I use "var_dump" to print out, what my "json_decode" returns. The response-header of this API response is "application/json", but I am not familiar with this json format.

The json response from the API looks like this:

```
[1,"Example name","307","7","Test","455",1458572100000]
[1,"Another example name","146","7","Test","455",1458571500000]
[1,"Test","304","7","Test","455",1458572280000]
[1,"Example name 3","163","7","Hello world","455",1458571080000]
```

This is the result/response of a single API request. Now, for example, I want to get the penultimate number (in this case everytime 455) of every line/object or, for example, the name (second value: "Example name", "Another example name", "Test" and so on). How can I do this with php and this json format? It would be nice, if I can get an array from this to iterate through.

It's a local realtime bus arrival API, but it's similar to/the same as `content.tfl.gov.uk/…`and I call this API with a simple http/get request using `file_get_contents` in PHP

```
"/interfaces/ura/instant_V1?returnList=stopID,stopPointName,LineID,DestinationT‌​ext,estimatedTime,vehicleID&vehicleID=455")
```

Comment: you got all 4 of those lines back from the api? then that's not valid json. it's 4 separate json arrays stuck together, which is illegal syntax for json. you'd have to explode this string on the newlines, then decode each separate line as a distinct json string.

Comment: Is that ONE RESPONSE from the API or 4 seperate responses from 4 seperate calls to the API?

Comment: Yes, all 4 of those lines are in one single response from the api with the http header "application/json". Depending on my request parameters, I can also get, of cource, more than 4 lines, sometimes 10, 50 or even 500 of those lines within one response.

Comment: Then either the API is rubbish or you are chopping off some wrapper text that makes that into proper JSON. Did you remove a `{` and a `}` from the beginning and end of the string that gets returned?

Comment: You have a problem with your JSON, it is wrong formated.

Comment: This is a single response of a third-party API with the http header "application/json" and I didn't remove or change anything. This is the unchanged "json" result and I havn't seen this before too.

Comment: Then whatever it is its not a json result. Can you tell us what API you are calling, and Show us your code for doing the call.

Comment: It's a local realtime bus arrival API, but it's similar to/the same as http://content.tfl.gov.uk/tfl-live-bus-river-bus-arrivals-api-documentation-v16.pdf and I call this API with a simple http/get request using "file_get_contents" in PHP ("/interfaces/ura/instant_V1?returnList=stopID,stopPointName,LineID,DestinationText,estimatedTime,vehicleID&vehicleID=455")

Comment: If you want to keep your code a big secret, we will have to do the same with our answers. Nobody here has time for a game of 20 questions. Show your code

Comment: But why should I show my code, when I already said, that I just use file_get_contents on this API url? My code is, at the moment, only this one file_get_contents line, which returns these 4 lines. Based on this response, I want to iterate through it as an array, but, as we all noticed, this format is based on JSON, but not "real JSON" and that's the problem, not the code. The code is, at the moment, just this line getting the response as a string and nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, that's **not JSON** format that you're getting back. But if that's what you're getting then you need a solution :)

I would ignore the first & last character and use [str_getcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) to return the comma separated string as an array:

```
$input = '[1,"Example name","307","7","Test","455",1458572100000]';
$array = str_getcsv(substr($input, 1, -1));
```

If you are having multple lines, then you'll want to split them into individual lines before doing the above with:

```
$lines = explode($input, "]");
$array = array();
foreach($lines AS $line) {
    $input = '[1,"Example name","307","7","Test","455",1458572100000]';
    $array[] = str_getcsv(substr($input, 1, -1));
}
```

*Updated to show delimeter of `]` instead of `\n` as per comment below.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This method works, but with "\n", I get my multiple lines (4) as one line and the php function "count" also returns "1", when I run it on $lines. Every "item" in my API response has it's own line, but inexplicably "\n" doesn't work for each line.

Comment: Now I used the last char "]" as delimeter and it works. Now I'm getting one array for each line.

Comment: Glad it's working. Updated answer with the different delimiter for you to accept the answer (although your example shows they are separated with new lines?).

Comment: If this works for you fine, but it is fixing a symptom of the problem and not fixing the real issue. As likely as not you will get situations that do not fit the workaround later on

Comment: Indeed, I indicate this in the answer. Let me make that message clearer for future visitors

Comment: Yes, it's separated with new lines, but '\n' doesn't work for whatever reason. I don't know. I know, that it's not the best solution, not only, because I'll get an array for each line and not a single array, where those lines are in as I would get it with real json (btw, the api documentation says "The API is based on JSON, however the responses deviate away from the JSON standard"). I could put this into one array, but it's not the best solution. Of course, if anybody knows a better or "the real" solution for this problem, I would be very happy about an answer.

Comment: Remember that your "JSON" response that you get is not JSON but just a string of comma text (comma separated). IMO my post is your best solution ... and it works!